# KSH Error : '$' unexpected

Tags: arrays, ksh

Below KSH script results in the error "Syntax error at line 4: '$' unexpected"

```
!#/bin/ksh
for i in `cat pins.list`
do
        set -A array_${i} `grep -i "$i " pins.txt | awk '{print $2}'`
        echo "Elements of array_${i} are ${array_${i}[@]}"
done

#=================================
```

I am creating multiple arrays (array_$i) for each iteration of i,  after parsing the file pins.txt.
I can see the arrays array_block , array_group, array_range created and the elements of pins.txt stored in these arrays correctly, but I am unable to print the values of each of these arrays due to this error.  Printing the contents of these 3 arrays outside the loop has no issues.  But I need to access these arrays inside the loop for further processing in my script.  Is there a way to resolve this?

Contents of pins.list and pins.txt are as follows:

```
pins.list (Arrays)
==================
block
group
range


pins.txt
===========

range     444
group     46
range     32
block     96
group     99
range     123
block     56
range     22
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a dynamic variable name in this way, you need `eval`.  For example:

```
while read i
do
    eval "set -A array_${i} \$(grep -i $i pins.txt | awk '{print $2}')"
    eval "echo \"Elements of array_${i} are \${array_${i}[@]}\" "
done < pins.list
```

I have changed from a `for` loop to a `while`, this is an alternative method of reading a file rather than using `cat` (also, check your #! line).

Comment: @user1758782: If you are happy with my answer then could you accept it please?